# How to start named (BIND)

Tags: macos, dns, bind

When I try to start named on my OS 10.7.3 machine, with the following command:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.isc.named.plist
```

... I get this error message:

```
launchctl: no plist was returned for: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.isc.named.plist
nothing found to load
```

What am I doing wrong?

In the absense of getting the above to work, I can start named manually, like so: `sudo /usr/sbin/named` ... but that's rather crude, isn't it?

What do I need to do go get `launchctl` working with named?

Also, the contents of my org.isc.named.plist file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>org.isc.named</string>
        <key>OnDemand</key>
        <false/>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/usr/sbin/named</string>
                <string>-f</string>
        </array>
        <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that there is actually a file named org.isc.named.plist in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons.

If there is, can you list the contents?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I've added the contents of `org.isc.named.plist` to my OP for you - thanks again.

Comment: what are the files permissions set as?

Comment: That was it! (Permissions) They were set to 600, when everything else in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` was set to 644. A simple `chmod 644 org.isc.named.plist` and it now starts automatically when I reboot - Thanks Dennis!